# ¿Porque Se imprime dos veces el mensaje en pantalla?

Tags: java, bucles

La idea del programa es que cada vez que evalúe los casos del switch entre otra vez en el ciclo while y vuelva a decir.. "Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):". Lo que no entiendo de mi codigo es por qué imprime Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): " dos veces en vez de imprimirlo una sola vez y evaluar de nuevo los casos.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void cantidadesAImprimir(long water, long milk, long coffeBeans, long disposableCups, long money) {

        System.out.println("The coofe machine has:");
        System.out.println(water + " of water");
        System.out.println(milk + " of milk");
        System.out.println(coffeBeans + " of coffee beans");
        System.out.println(disposableCups + " of disposable cups");
        System.out.println(money + " of money");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        long water = 400;
        long milk = 540;
        long coffeBeans = 120;
        long disposableCups = 9;
        long money = 550;

        String option = "";

        while (!option.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, exit): ");
            option = scanner.nextLine();
            switch (option) {
                case "buy":
                    System.out.println("What do you want to buy? 1 - espresso, 2 - latte, 3 - cappuccino:");
                    int option2 = scanner.nextInt();
                    switch (option2) {
                        case 1:
                            water -= 250;
                            coffeBeans -= 16;
                            money += 4;
                            disposableCups -= 1;
                            break;

                        case 2:

                            water -= 350;
                            milk -= 20;
                            coffeBeans -= 75;
                            money += 7;
                            disposableCups -= 1;

                            break;

                        case 3:

                            water -= 200;
                            milk -= 100;
                            coffeBeans -= 12;
                            money += 6;
                            disposableCups -= 1;
                            break;
                        default:
                            System.out.println("Incorrec Option");
                    }
                    System.out.println("I have enough resources, making you a coffee!");
                    break;

            case "fill":
                System.out.println("Write how many ml of water do you want to add: ");
                long waterToAdd = scanner.nextLong();
                water += waterToAdd;

                System.out.println("Write how many ml of milk do you want to add: ");
                long milkToAdd = scanner.nextLong();
                milk += milkToAdd;

                System.out.println("Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add: ");
                long coffeToAdd = scanner.nextLong();
                coffeBeans += coffeToAdd;

                System.out.println("Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add: ");
                long cupsToAdd = scanner.nextLong();
                disposableCups += cupsToAdd;
                break;

            case "take":
                System.out.println("I gave you " + money + "$");
                money = 0;
                break;
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de salida 1:  si escribo buy: el programa imprime:

I have enough resources, making you a coffee!
Write action (buy, fill, take, exit):
Write action (buy, fill, take, exit):

Ejemplo de salida 2: si escribo fill: el programa imprime:

Write how many ml of water do you want to add:
1
Write how many ml of milk do you want to add:
2
Write how many grams of coffee beans do you want to add:
3
Write how many disposable cups of coffee do you want to add:
4
Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):
Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit):

como pueden notar La linea Write action (buy, fill, take, remaining, exit): se imprime dos veces y no entiendo porque. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te imprime dos veces porque esta leyendo los fin de lines de que deja el ultimo scanner.nextLong() o scanner.nextInt(). cuando escribes el exit lo que realmente llega primero es el fin de línea del anterior scanner, por lo tanto opcion queda en blanco y no pasa la el segunda. Luego lee el exit y finaliza.
Asegúrate de leer los enters que dejan los nextInt o nextLong o agregale al while la condición option==""

Answer (score 0):

Trata de sacar cuando pides al usuario que ingrese una opción fuera del ciclo while, ya que tu lo tienes dentro del ciclo.

```
String option = "";

        System.out.println("Write action (buy, fill, take, exit): ");
        option = scanner.nextLine();

        while (!option.equals("exit")) {
```

Resultado con la opción "buy"
[image: Resultado con la opción "buy"]

Resultado con la opción "fill"
[image: Resultado con la opción "fill"]

Comment: Te imprime dos  veces porque esta leyendo los fin de lines de que deja el ultimo scanner.nextLong() o scanner.nextInt(). cuando escribes el exit lo que realmente llega primero es el fin de línea del anterior scanner,  por lo tanto opcion queda en blanco y no pasa la el segunda. Luego lee el exit y finaliza

Comment: Asegúrate de leer los enters que dejan los nextInt o nextLong o agregale al while la condición option==""

Comment: Gracias @JuanCarlosGuibovich, no estaba tomando en cuenta que cuando introducimos un valor con un scanner el programa lee tanto el valor como el enter. Lo solucione leyendo los enter como me indicaste, colocando un nextLine debajo de cada scanner numerico sin asignarlo a ninguna variable. Fue de gran ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Lo pongo como solución